Is "@angular/material" 14.2.7 version work with angular 17?
I want to upgrade my angular version to 17 but do not want to upgrade my material version. I want to keep it on 14.2.7 as I am using it with legacy peer deps on angular 16 wanted to use it with same way on angular 17. Is it possible?
Expecting to upgrade on angular 17 with material library version on 14

No you will have many issues and is not suggested.

as angular 16 removes ngcc support completely so is it possible to go with angular material 14 library version on angular 16 with --force

It's technically possible, but it isn't recommended.
By using --force you can ignore dependency warnings
so in this case it would be:
ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16 --force


As angular 16 removes ngcc support completely so is it possible to go with angular material 14 library version on angular 16 with --force.
The reason is Angular libraries built with View Engine cannot be used in Angular v16+.
